# Is my Outlook 2007 add-in is trusted?

Tags: c#, security, outlook, outlook-addin

i have done to create a outlook 2007 addin using Visual studio2010.

once i run the addin,i get the current outlook mail address for accessing some process.

at that time,i got a warning popup?

how to avoid or disable that warning programmatically(c#)?

How to know my addin is trusted?if not trusted means how can i make my addin trusted?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://www.add-in-express.com/docs/outlook-security-manager-addins.php) behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you get a security prompt in an add-in, that means that you are not using the Outlook.Application object passed to your addin.

See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for the list of your options.